# Customized Button

Tags: c#, winforms, button

How I can make a button like this in WinForms?

[image]

It always like this

[image]

Comment: set the transparency colour

Comment: ..don't draw the border and `FontStyle.Bold` the text.. ? Can you show us the code you have?

Comment: Sayce - does not work :(

Comment: @SimonWhitehead - don't have code. I just set the background image with the picture

Comment: I just tried it myself and it does remove the backcolour of the button, but it also makes the form transparent, sorry

Comment: I think the caption should say "Tylenol" :)

Comment: To be honest to render buttons like that I have always used a third party control called [3D control Magic](http://www.multimediasoft.com/3dcm/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround (to remove border) you can set `Button.FlatStyle` to `Flat` and set `Button.FlatAppearance.BorderSize` to `0`. Also you can modify `FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor`/`MouseOverBackColor`.

Answer (score 4):

I coded this which is not a complete solution but can help you see it in action and go further to make your own button:

```
public class RoundButton : Button
{
    GraphicsPath borderPath;
    protected override void OnSizeChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnSizeChanged(e);
        UpdateRegion();
    }
    private void UpdateRegion()
    {
        borderPath = new GraphicsPath();
        borderPath.AddArc(new Rectangle(0, 0, Height, Height), 90, 180);
        borderPath.AddLine(new Point(Height / 2, 0), new Point(Width - Height / 2, 0));
        borderPath.AddArc(new Rectangle(Width - Height, 0, Height, Height), -90, 180);
        borderPath.AddLine(new Point(Width - Height / 2, Height), new Point(Height / 2, Height));
        Region = new Region(borderPath);
    }
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pevent)
    {
        pevent.Graphics.Clear(Color.Black);            
        Color cl1 = isMouseOver ? Color.FromArgb(100, Color.Yellow) : Color.FromArgb(100, Color.Aqua);
        Color cl2 = isMouseOver ? Color.Yellow : Color.Aqua;
        if (MouseButtons == MouseButtons.Left) cl2 = cl1;
        using (LinearGradientBrush brush = new LinearGradientBrush(ClientRectangle, cl1, cl2, 90))
        {
            pevent.Graphics.FillPath(brush, borderPath);
            pevent.Graphics.ScaleTransform(0.8f, 0.4f);                
            pevent.Graphics.TranslateTransform(0.1f * ClientSize.Width, 0.1f * ClientSize.Height, MatrixOrder.Append);
        }
        if(!(MouseButtons == MouseButtons.Left)) 
            pevent.Graphics.FillPath(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(100, Color.White)), borderPath);
        pevent.Graphics.ResetTransform();

        pevent.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        float penSize = MouseButtons == MouseButtons.Left ? 4 : 2.5f;
        using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Gray) { Width = penSize })
        {
            pevent.Graphics.DrawPath(pen, borderPath);
        }
        using (StringFormat sf = new StringFormat { LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center, Alignment = StringAlignment.Center })
        {
            Rectangle rect = ClientRectangle;
            if (MouseButtons == MouseButtons.Left) rect.Offset(-1, -1);
            pevent.Graphics.DrawString(Text, Font, new SolidBrush(ForeColor), rect, sf);
        }
    }
    bool isMouseOver;        
    protected override void OnMouseEnter(EventArgs e)
    {
         base.OnMouseEnter(e);
         isMouseOver = true;             
    }
    protected override void OnMouseLeave(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseLeave(e);
        isMouseOver = false;            
    }        
}
```

Here is its look:

[image]

If you swap the `cl1` and `cl2` in the `new LinearGradientBrush(...)`, the button will look different like this:

[image]

Comment: Your answer is much more elaborate than mine and provides a better solution for the specific problem (I was the one who +1 it in the first place). Nonetheless, it is perhaps too complex and not so easily generalisable, thus I will better let mine just as an  alternative for readers looking for more generic solutions.

Comment: @varocarbas thank you, my code is not such elaborate, it uses the most basic concepts here including `Region, GraphicsPath, Graphics, LinearGradientBrush` and a little `Transform`. I used `ScaleTransform` and `TranslateTransform` to transform the existing `borderPath` into the smaller one, that's kind of laziness, the best solution is create a method receiving a `Rectangle` and returning the corresponding `borderPath` and with that approach, we don't need any transformation and the code would look `simpler` to people who are not familiar with `Transform`.

Answer (score 0):

You can redraw the contour of the button by affecting its `.Region` property. Here you have a sample code I wrote some time ago (and have quickly converted from VB.NET right now) showing how to create a button shaped as an ellipse, button2, and as a complex polygon (an X), button1.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;

    namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                GraphicsPath pathPolygon = new GraphicsPath(FillMode.Winding);
                GraphicsPath pathEllipse = new GraphicsPath(FillMode.Winding);


                //------ POLYGON (X)
                Point[] points = new Point[12];
                points[0].X = 5;
                points[0].Y = 15;
                points[1].X = 10;
                points[1].Y = 10;
                points[2].X = 18;
                points[2].Y = 18;
                points[3].X = 26;
                points[3].Y = 10;
                points[4].X = 31;
                points[4].Y = 15;
                points[5].X = 23;
                points[5].Y = 23;
                points[6].X = 31;
                points[6].Y = 31;
                points[7].X = 26;
                points[7].Y = 36;
                points[8].X = 18;
                points[8].Y = 28;
                points[9].X = 10;
                points[9].Y = 36;
                points[10].X = 5;
                points[10].Y = 31;
                points[11].X = 13;
                points[11].Y = 23;

                Point maxVals = new Point(31, 36);

                pathPolygon.AddPolygon(points);

                Region region = new Region(pathPolygon);

                button1.BackColor = Color.Red;
                button1.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
                button1.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
                button1.Region = region;
                button1.SetBounds(button1.Location.X, button1.Location.Y, maxVals.X, maxVals.Y);

                Rectangle ellipse = new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 50);
                maxVals = new Point(100, 50);
                pathEllipse.AddEllipse(ellipse);
                region = new Region(pathEllipse);

                button2.BackColor = Color.Red;
                button2.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
                button2.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
                button2.Region = region;
                button2.SetBounds(button2.Location.X, button2.Location.Y, maxVals.X, maxVals.Y);

            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see, the ellipse option is much simpler, but also much less flexible (although it might be the best solution for what you are looking for; bear in mind that you can play with the width/height in `.SetBounds` to "cut the shape"). The polygon seems a bit complicated but is pretty straightforward once you get used to the proceeding: come up with all the points required to draw the contour you want (e.g., for a rectangle, you need 4 points, the 4 vertices) and input them in the code I provide (don't forget to include the maximum X/Y values in maxVals).

Answer (score -1):

You can add the click event on image button